# MY CODE CREATES A JSON WITH NO DATA IN IT

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am learning web scraping with scrapy. I wrote the following code that I know works for other people. It is vary basic

```
import scrapy


class jumboSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'jumbo'
start_urls = [
    'https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS'
]

def parse(self, response):
     prize = response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()').getall()

     yield {
         'prize': prize
     }
```

Then I go to the terminal and write the following command

scrapy crawl jumbo -o jumbo.json

to create a json file in which will be the data I am extracting with the xpath sentence. I already made sure the xpath response is right. When I use the same xpath in scrapy shell it brings the data with no issues

The problem is that the file created by the code is empty. No data is shown.

I do not know if this happens to someone else

Any help is more than appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

`.getall()` method produces a list and list can't grab data as `string/text` that's why it must iterate over the list of elements then extract desired data as follows:

## Script:

```
import scrapy
class jumboSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jumbo'
    start_urls = ['https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS']

    def parse(self, response):
        for price in response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]'):

            yield {
                'price': price.xpath('.//text()').get()}
```

## Output:

```
{'price': '$2.249.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$2.579.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$2.999.900'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$2.399.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$2.399.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$2.499.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$3.449.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.699.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.769.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.799.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$949.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.659.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.815.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.815.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.749.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$4.799.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$799.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.199.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.399.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.799.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.299.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.139.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.629.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$5.239.000'}
2021-12-09 03:51:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.alkosto.com/computadores-tablet/computadores-portatiles/c/BI_104_ALKOS>
{'price': '$1.799.000'}
```